# Eclipse Maven dependencies in Run Configurations?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a Maven project in Eclipse that successfully reaches the "package" goal.  In doing so it produces a jar.  I need to include that jar as well as the Maven dependencies in a Java Application Run Configuration.

My problem is that when I set up the run configuration, and provide command line arguments, classes provided by Maven are not found.

How is this supposed to happen?  I've tried exploring, experimenting and searching.  I could manually add all the jars from my local `.m2/repository` directory as "external jars" in Eclipse, but it doesn't seem right that I should have to do that.

Comment: Figured it out.  Build maven goal `eclipse:eclipse` then refresh then the run configuration will have what it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `mvn install` to put the .jar files in the local repository, and then add appropriate `<dependency/>` stanza to your `pom.xml` file.

Comment: The first time I tried this I did not hit F5 to refresh afterwards.  It appeared not to work.  `mvn install` seems to be equivalent to `mvn eclipse:eclipse` when run within Eclipse.